# how to use controller component in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to validate [MuiPhoneInput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number) using react hook form (v7.43.1).
The useForm looks like

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
  } = useForm();
```

The controller component looks like

```
           <Controller
              name="phone"
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <MuiPhoneInput
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  defaultCountry={"il"}
                  variant={"outlined"}
                  error={!!errors.phone}
                  helperText={errors?.phone?.message}
                />
              )}
              rules={{
                required: "Phone is required",
              }}
            />
```

But I can't write anything in the input. I tried with other textfields, but nothing works. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're very close except your `MuiPhoneInput` is losing reference from the `field` destructure you're using to get `value` and `onChange`. There's an important `ref` that needs to be set contained inside `field`. Here's the official [example](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/V7/customMaskedInputWithController.tsx) of a `Controller` component handling a custom masked input.

Here's my [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hook-form-material-ui-phone-number-v4d12x) that demonstrates integrating [material-ui-phone-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-material-ui) with [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/).

- Since you're setting `defaultCountry={"il"}` on the MUI component, also set the default value that resolves to inside `defaultValues` so `react-hook-form` knows about it.
- Adds validation via `isNotFilledTel()` used inside `rules>validate` object.
- Handling a React.StrictMode issue where ref.focus is `undefined`.

**app.js**

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import MuiPhoneInput from "material-ui-phone-number";

export default function App() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
  } = useForm({
    reValidateMode: "onSubmit",
    defaultValues: {
      phone: "+972",
    },
  });

  const isNotFilledTel = (v: string) => {
    return v.length < 15 ? "Phone number is required." : undefined;
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        name="phone"
        control={control}
        rules={{
          required: "Phone is required",
          validate: {
            inputTelRequired: isNotFilledTel,
          },
        }}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <MuiPhoneInput
              {...field}
              ref={(ref) => {
                if (ref && !ref.focus) ref.focus = () => {};
              }}
              defaultCountry={"il"}
              variant={"outlined"}
              error={!!errors.phone}
              helperText={<>{errors?.phone?.message}</>}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      {errors.phone && <p>Phone is required.</p>}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```